# when Flutter build a web files... dont insert assets image, in his assetes folder

Tags: flutter

I have a working project, that have some images that appears in android device!
But... when build web part (with comand: flutter build web)  create a working project without images;
in build/web folder there is no assets folder...

flutter program:
[image]

pubspecc.yaml
[image]

...in build/web/assets there is no images folder!!!!!!!

i dont know how to solve, because in pubspect.yaml there is declaration and that images are visible in android part!!

thank!

Answer (score 3):

try to add inside your `pubspec.yaml`,

```
assets/images/
```

and then press packages get.

Comment: yess yess.. now i undestand... i dont know why in android part functions! without problem

Comment: i think you are expert... can i ask to you why; when i open index.html in we folder with only browser i found 6 error like:   _Access to XMLHttpRequest at ...fileWeb    _Uncaught Failed to load asset at "assets/FontManifest.json"  _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$3' of null
   and other 3 errors but..... if i start one http-server on that folder functions without problem?

Comment: I am not an expert :D, I am just learning like you. I  don't understand what are you talking about. also, accept the answer if that helped

Comment: no nothing, is my stupid error... which I understood 5 minutes after posting the question